# How to release resources of containers in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running some programs inside containers within Kubernetes and use Prometheus for plotting some metrics like CPU utilization over a specific period of time, network I/O and so on.
Basically the programs are encrypting some images I uploaded into a shared folder and for some reasons which I am not aware of, when the programs stops running inside the containers, their resource consumptions do not come back to the initial state (e.g., 0 CPU utilization) before encryption. Not sure if the resources are not released by Kubernetes or whatsoever.
Any help ?

Comment: Sounds like your code has a memory leak and kubernetes has no control over that.  (for example, you open a file-handle and use-it, but never close it)

Comment: Is the pod exiting and that's just the last datapoint for that container or pod?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, how to detect such memory leak ? the running program was generated using cx_freeze python.

Comment: @jordanm the container is the only datapoint and there is no other container connected to it.

Comment: Well, you call open method to create a file, but never close it, like I said

Comment: Also, you really don't need cx_freeze for running python code in a container

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I used cx_freeze to generate the binary (to be executed later) from the python source code as it was not supposed to be shared with other people.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.